# Can't find variable: document ReactNative Js

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, expo

I try to use Stripe API. 
When i load : https://js.stripe.com/v3 and at the end of the **Feed.js** file

I got the error below:

> Can't find variable: document

I am unable to use Stripe Api because of this error, does someone know what am I missing ?

I'm using Expo and i tried `import storybook` but it didn't solve my problem. Below the **index.html** file And my **Feed.js** File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>demo | react-stripe-elements</title>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body,
    html {
      background-color: #f6f9fc;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #32325d;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 40px;
      margin: 20px 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .Checkout {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 800px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    label {
      color: #6b7c93;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    }
    button {
      white-space: nowrap;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      padding: 0 14px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.025em;
      background-color: #6772e5;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
      transition: all 150ms ease;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    form {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #e6ebf1;
    }
    button:hover {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #7795f8;
      transform: translateY(-1px);
      box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    }
    input,
    .StripeElement {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
      box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0196078) 0px 1px 0px;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: white;
    }
    input::placeholder {
      color: #aab7c4;
    }
    input:focus,
    .StripeElement--focus {
      box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.109804) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0784314) 0px 1px 3px;
      -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
      transition: all 150ms ease;
    }
    .StripeElement.IdealBankElement,
    .StripeElement.PaymentRequestButton {
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="App">
  </div>
  <script src="/Ecran/UtilisateurConnecte/BottomTab/Feed.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**feed.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import type {InjectedProps} from '../../../src/components/inject';


import {
  CardElement,
  CardNumberElement,
  CardExpiryElement,
  CardCVCElement,
  PaymentRequestButtonElement,
  IbanElement,
  IdealBankElement,
  StripeProvider,
  Elements,
  injectStripe,
} from '../../../src/index';

const handleBlur = () => {
  console.log('[blur]');
};
const handleChange = (change) => {
  console.log('[change]', change);
};
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log('[click]');
};
const handleFocus = () => {
  console.log('[focus]');
};
const handleReady = () => {
  console.log('[ready]');
};

const createOptions = (fontSize, padding) => {
  return {
    style: {
      base: {
        fontSize,
        color: '#424770',
        letterSpacing: '0.025em',
        fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro, monospace',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4',
        },
        padding,
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#9e2146',
      },
    },
  };
};

class _CardForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createToken()
        .then((payload) => console.log('[token]', payload));
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe.js hasn't loaded yet.");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Card details
          <CardElement
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const CardForm = injectStripe(_CardForm);

class _SplitForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createToken()
        .then((payload) => console.log('[token]', payload));
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe.js hasn't loaded yet.");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Card number
          <CardNumberElement
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Expiration date
          <CardExpiryElement
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          CVC
          <CardCVCElement
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Postal code
          <PostalCodeElement
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const SplitForm = injectStripe(_SplitForm);

class _PaymentRequestForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const paymentRequest = props.stripe.paymentRequest({
      country: 'US',
      currency: 'usd',
      total: {
        label: 'Demo total',
        amount: 1000,
      },
    });

    paymentRequest.on('token', ({complete, token, ...data}) => {
      console.log('Received Stripe token: ', token);
      console.log('Received customer information: ', data);
      complete('success');
    });

    paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then((result) => {
      this.setState({canMakePayment: !!result});
    });

    this.state = {
      canMakePayment: false,
      paymentRequest,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.canMakePayment ? (
      <PaymentRequestButtonElement
        className="PaymentRequestButton"
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onReady={handleReady}
        paymentRequest={this.state.paymentRequest}
        style={{
          paymentRequestButton: {
            theme: 'dark',
            height: '64px',
            type: 'donate',
          },
        }}
      />
    ) : null;
  }
}
const PaymentRequestForm = injectStripe(_PaymentRequestForm);

class _IbanForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createSource({
          type: 'sepa_debit',
          currency: 'eur',
          owner: {
            name: ev.target.name.value,
            email: ev.target.email.value,
          },
          mandate: {
            notification_method: 'email',
          },
        })
        .then((payload) => console.log('[source]', payload));
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe.js hasn't loaded yet.");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name
          <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Jane Doe" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          Email
          <input
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="jane.doe@example.com"
            required
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          IBAN
          <IbanElement
            supportedCountries={['SEPA']}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const IbanForm = injectStripe(_IbanForm);

class _IdealBankForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createSource({
          type: 'ideal',
          amount: 1099,
          currency: 'eur',
          owner: {
            name: ev.target.name.value,
          },
          redirect: {
            return_url: 'https://example.com',
          },
        })
        .then((payload) => console.log('[source]', payload));
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe.js hasn't loaded yet.");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name
          <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Jane Doe" required />
        </label>
        <label>
          iDEAL Bank
          <IdealBankElement
            className="IdealBankElement"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize, '10px 14px')}
          />
        </label>
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const IdealBankForm = injectStripe(_IdealBankForm);

class Checkout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      elementFontSize: window.innerWidth < 450 ? '14px' : '18px',
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 450 && this.state.elementFontSize !== '14px') {
        this.setState({elementFontSize: '14px'});
      } else if (
        window.innerWidth >= 450 &&
        this.state.elementFontSize !== '18px'
      ) {
        this.setState({elementFontSize: '18px'});
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {elementFontSize} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Checkout">
        <h1>Available Elements</h1>
        <Elements>
          <CardForm fontSize={elementFontSize} />
        </Elements>
        <Elements>
          <SplitForm fontSize={elementFontSize} />
        </Elements>
        <Elements>
          <PaymentRequestForm />
        </Elements>
        <Elements>
          <IbanForm fontSize={elementFontSize} />
        </Elements>
        <Elements>
          <IdealBankForm fontSize={elementFontSize} />
        </Elements>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh">
      <Checkout />
    </StripeProvider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.App'));
```

Comment: Are you usen Text and View from react native in html ? ... that's not gonna work. You cannot use html as your core in react native

Comment: Even if i delete my index.html i got the error Can't find variable: document @ValdaXD

Comment: i'm trying to play video from youtube using plyr player , having the same error, anyone knows the reason.

Comment: @BharathiV - I just installed stripe in ReactJS by downloading the js file and importing https://js.stripe.com/v3/ as a local js file. I get this error and found your question. Did you find a React solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Taersious Did you found an aswer ?

Comment: @Dorian - I am good for now. Making calls to stripe api works, but I am now facing a different issue with SSL mode on my localhost.

Comment: @Taersious May I ask you to explain me how you did in answer ? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware my solution is not yet working in localhost, due to Stripe constraint that requires secure transmission between the post action. My localhost is using self-signed cert, but this is not sufficient for Stripe. I will need to publish the site to a site running in SSL mode.

My solution does not implement any html as you have done. Instead, I am using React app for front end which communicates to an Express app for back end, both running on the same server, but under their own port. For example React runs on port 3000, and Express runs on port 8000. Express app has a package.json line for stripe as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "passport-stripe": "^0.2.3",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
        "stripe": "^7.8.0"
      },
```

Then in the React app, I have the following in package.json for Stripe:

```
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^4.0.1",
```

And a component page like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
//import { StripeProvider, Elements, CardNumberElement } from 'react-stripe-elements';

import '../App.css'
import Styles from '../components/Styles'
import Checkout from '../stripe/Checkout';

export default class Give extends Component {
    render() { 

        return (

            <div className="topSpace">

                <View style={Styles.backroundView}>

                    <View style={Styles.mainView}>
                        <Text>
                            Click to pay with card:
                        </Text>
                        <Checkout
                            name={'Test Sending A Charge'}
                            description={'This will send a checkout to stripe api'}
                            amount={1}
                        />
                    </View>

                </View>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Glad that you coulp help me !